# Can I modify the jQuery library?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, npm

I want to modify the `jQuery.post` function to handle the CORS problem.

Because the `jQuery.ajax` needs me to write lots of code like

```
$.ajax({
    url:'',
    data:null,
    type:'post',
    xhrFields:{withCredentials:true},
    crossDomain:true,
    success:function(res){}
});
```

It's boring.
So I want to modify `jQuery.post` to add some properties.
So I added some code in ajax.js. After I build that, it seems nothing changed.
Is there something in Node?

Comment: by the way,I am using node.js to download jQuery

Comment: You can modify anything, really.  But I might suggest you look at `ajaxSetup` rather than changing the library method.  Or, write your own function in your own namespace that does your common work.  The hesitancy of modifying a standardized library function to your logic, is that other programmers that come after you may not be aware of the changes.  And that can lead to major confusion.

Comment: Yes, you can, but it's not a good idea. Extension is better than modification. That said, how exactly are you planning to solve the 'CORS problem', given that the lack of CORS headers is not an issue which can be solved in JS.

Comment: Why not just write a wrapper function that abstracts away the parameters you don't want to keep typing, and then use that for your post calls instead? That way you aren't introducing instability just to save a few monotonous key strokes.

Comment: don't modify the core code - just extend it and fix that way with an alternative method name

Comment: Thanks ,wrapper is a better solution to me.Modify the core code sounds like more dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just write your own wrapper like the following:

```
$.myAjax = function(o) {
   var opt = $.extend({ default options here }, o);

   return $.ajax(opt);
}
```

This just simply defines a utility to call `$.ajax`, and defines a set of default values that you commonly use.  The `myAjax` wrapper can be defined on anything, and doesn't have to be a defined as a custom widget on the jQuery object.

I would not modify the library files themselves - that allows you to continue to receive updates through whatever package management software you use, and not to have to worry about overwriting anything you customized.

Answer (score 0):

You control the CORS on the server side that receives the ajax call not in the ajax call itself.

However if you want feel free to modify $.ajax as you please:

```
$.ajax = () =>
{
    console.log("I shouldn't be doing this.");
  // Here comes my new implementation
  alert("Ajaaaaaaaax !!");
}

$.ajax();
```

Comment: "feel free to modify $.ajax as you please" ... however, it's recommended that you don't.  a) you'll forget and then wonder why it doesn't work on your next project b) you'll forget and wonder why $.ajax doesn't work anywhere else c) someone else won't know about it if they ever use your code d) in the future you'll upgrade to the next version which will overwrite your changes and (having forgotten your dodgy "patch") you won't know why it doesn't work and blame the new jquery.

Comment: Hey, I agree completely with you. You should never modify this kind of things.